# Simply connectedness of a semisimple complex algebraic group: algebraic and topological

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

$
\newcommand{\C}{{\Bbb C}}
$Let $G$ be a connected semisimple algebraic group over the field of complex numbers $\C$.
Assume that $G$ is simply connected: any surjective homomorphism with finite kernel
$$G'\to G$$
where $G'$ is a connected semisimple algebraic group over $\C$,
is an isomorphism.

From this we can deduce  that the corresponding  complex Lie group $G(\C)$
is simply connected in topological sense: any continuous  loop
$$ \theta\colon [0,1] \to G(\C)\qquad \text{such that}\quad \theta(0)=\theta(1)= 1_G$$
is contractible.

I am looking for a **reference** for this deduction.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1660961/are-the-c-points-of-a-simply-connected-algbraic-group-simply-connected). However, I am not quite happy with the answer there, and I am looking for a reference rather than a proof.

Comment: I am also unhappy with the linked proof. The proof that I know reduces to two standard references: (1) (topological) $\pi_1$ is finitely generated abelian (in fact, finite, but one does not need this), (2) a finite analytical  covering of a smooth complex algebraic variety is again algebraic (this is in Grothendieck's SGA 1 "Revetements Etales...", Exp. XII, but maybe there is a better reference). The desired conclusion is then immediate.

Comment: Fix a maximal torus $T$ of $G$. Then, $G$ is simply connected if and only if the associated root system $R(G,T)$ is simply connected. The claim then follows from Proposition D.4.1 of http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Thank you! I included the refernence to Brian Conrad into my paper.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Of course! And, I apologize for the lackluster explanation in the other thread.